Why won’t TypeScript let me import a type from an ES module into a CommonJS module?
I’m writing a Node.js app in TypeScript. Here’s a simplified version of my files so far:
// package.json
{ "type": "module" }

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "nodenext"
  }
}

// types.ts
export interface Options {}

// processOptions.cts
import type { Options } from "./types.ts";

I’m getting the following error in processOptions.cts:

error TS1479: The current file is a CommonJS module whose imports will produce 'require' calls; however, the referenced file is an ECMAScript module and cannot be imported with 'require'. Consider writing a dynamic 'import("./types.ts")' call instead.

I understand that processOptions.cts is CommonJS and types.ts is ESM because of their file extensions and my package.json "type" field, but the error is on an import type statement, which gets completely erased from my JavaScript output. It’s not going to produce a require call; it’s going to produce nothing! What is TypeScript talking about? Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Is this a bug? Kind of.
The error message is indeed confusing and misleading—you’re correct that there is no runtime representation of an import type statement, so the fact that the error message says it will become a require call and suggests writing a dynamic import is a bug. However, this code is intended to have an error. In TypeScript 5.7, the error message was updated to say

Type-only import of an ECMAScript module from a CommonJS module must have a 'resolution-mode' attribute.

...which doesn’t answer the question of why the import is an error, which I’ll come back to, but it does answer your next question:
Is there a workaround? Yes!
Since TypeScript 5.3, the error can be silenced by adding a resolution-mode import attribute:
import type { Options } from "./types.ts" with { "resolution-mode": "import" };

or, in type import form:
const options: import("./types.ts", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }) = {};

The resolution-mode import attribute, which is only supported on type-space imports, tells the TypeScript compiler whether to resolve the module specifier like Node.js would resolve a CommonJS require or an ESM import, which use completely separate module resolution algorithms. (In this example, both "require" and "import" would work because the module specifier is a relative path including the file extension. If the module specifier had been "./types", only "require" would work, since the Node.js ESM module resolution algorithm does not support omitting file extensions on relative paths.)
Why is this an error?
Instead of the example with "./types.ts", imagine that the error came from an import of a third-party dependency that ships only ESM code:
// processOptions.cts
import type { Options } from "remark-mdx";

Since the importing file is .cts, this type-only import resolves using the require algorithm, but it resolves to an ES module—remark-mdx does not contain any CommonJS. Now suppose that the authors of remark-mdx decided to begin shipping a CommonJS build alongside the ESM in the package, using package.json conditional "exports". Adding a conditionally loaded legacy build should be a backward compatible change, right? Well, not for the type checking of processOptions.cts. If remark-mdx adds new types that resolve under the require algorithm in a patch bump, that could change the type of Options. But if we explicitly specify with { "resolution-mode": "import" }, we can be pretty sure that our code will be unaffected by remark-mdx’s hypothetical decision to add a CommonJS entrypoint.
This concern is about protecting the ability of external package authors to make backward-compatible changes via package.json "exports". It really doesn’t apply at all to relative imports of your own files that you control. However, it was decided that, for consistency, the error should not be conditional on whether the import module specifier is relative. There is a lot of discussion about this on the TypeScript issue tracker, linked from the PR that changed the error message.
